# QTcpSocket does not emit error signal

Tags: c++, qt, networking

I have faced with a weird problem. When I try to connect, for example to offline server on `127.0.0.1:8080`, socket signal emits "error" as it should but when I connect to `127.0.0.10:8080` or `127.123.4.5:8080` signal does not emit errors. What's the problem and how can I catch failed connection error?

Code 1:

> ```
> remote_server = new Server(nickname, ip, port);
>
> connect(remote_server, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
>         SLOT(connection_failed(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
>
> remote_server->establish_connection();
> ```

Code 2:

> ```
> master_socket = std::move(
>             std::unique_ptr<QTcpSocket>(new QTcpSocket(nullptr))
>             );
> connect(master_socket.get(), SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
>         SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
>
> master_socket->connectToHost(ip.c_str(), port);
> master_socket->waitForConnected(2000);
> ```

Comment: If your servers listen on loopback interface (which is 127.0.0.1/8) then both your addresses (127.0.0.10, 127.123.4.5) will be up and available. Could you please provide "netstat -nap | grep LISTEN" output to clarify your issue?

Answer (score 0):

if your tcp socket is in another thread ( seperate from ui thread ) use

`connect(socket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
                this, SLOT(displayError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)) , Qt::DirectConnection);`

Qt::DirectConnection